# What is the novel written about a middle age woman finding/discovering magic

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

It was a Facebook post that said something like, "How come it is always kids and teens who find their way into magic, why not older women?" Well, there is a book with that plot -- an older woman finding magic/wizardry/a magical land.  I didn't remember the name of the book, though it may have had a Mrs. in the title.  I also got the impression it was a relatively new published book (within the past few years?)

Comment: Hi Sadie, do you remember any other details? Are there books that you've read that are similar to it? Was it young adult? Anything you can add that might help narrow it down.

Comment: You can check out the [handy guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for more hints of additional things you might be able to recall.

Comment: There are probably dozens of books meeting those parameters - I can think of two different novels / series just by Holly Lisle.  As per the other comments, especially more information on the protagonist - what does "older" mean?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Probably something like 19. :-P  (Just my cynical take on modern mass-market fantasy.)

Comment: Dang it... the novel was first put forward as a "I wish someone would write this book" prompt about an elderly woman finding magic, accompanied by her dozens of cats and a grandson (handsome younger neighbor?) who follows her and tries to keep her safe and get her to take her pills. And yes, someone wrote it somewhere in 2019 or 2020.

Comment: Paul Magrs wrote quite a few fantasy novels with middle-aged/older women as protagonists. Google "Brenda and Effie" (the Bride of Frankenstein - whose body is breaking down, and who only wanted to peacefully run a B&B - has to protect modern-day Whitby with her witch friend Effie) or "Iris Wildthyme" (a fun-loving old Time Lady with a bit of a drink problem, whose TARDIS looks like a London bus and whose companion is a talking stuffed panda.)

Comment: @Sadie: When you return, if you believe your question has been correctly answered, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica: {nods} But in this case, the mention of the Facebook post fairly clearly indicated the one case. Which... I probably ought to modify the question a bit to make that more clear. It's kind of lost in the reading to my mind.

Answer (score 12):

*[Mrs. Perivale and the Blue Fire Crystal](https://www.amazon.ca/Mrs-Perivale-Blue-Fire-Crystal/dp/154404402X)* published in 2017 by Dash Hoffman

[image: Cover of Mrs. Perivale and the Blue Fire Crystal]

> There is a Prophecy… A 73 year old woman who is told she is too old to be useful to anyone. A strange creature who has risked everything because he’s certain he’s right. An element crystal stolen from a temple, throwing the world into chaos. An unknown country; dangerous, beautiful, wild, magical, unimaginable. A journey almost no one believes that the old woman can undertake. The mysterious dark force bent on total destruction. Seven vastly different cats. One delicate butler. Life can’t be over. There’s a whole world to save and tea is at four. *As per the viral meme sent out by @yabroodingauthor "It's amazing how many prophecies involve teens. You'd think they'd pick more emotionally stable people, with more free time. Like Grandmas." to which @Dinurial replied, "I would read the hell out of a series of a chosen 85yo woman who goes on epic journeys throughout a dangerous and magical land armed only with a cane and her stab-tastic knitting needles accompanied by her six cats and her skittish-yet-devoted orderly who makes sure she takes her pills on time." WISH GRANTED. Mrs. Alice Perivale is finished with her life. At 73 years old she is told that she is useless to the world and she begins to wonder if it’s true, until she meets the most unusual creature she has ever seen, and finds herself in a realm she never could have imagined, on a journey almost no one believes that she can undertake. Against all odds, she accepts the prophesied challenge and she embarks on an adventure to save the strange realm she is in. She must find her way through a bizarre and wild world to take back the Blue Fire Crystal; a powerful and vital gem stolen by a dark force no one has ever seen, hidden away in a palace no one has ever found. She does not go alone. She is accompanied by her seven loyal cats; Tao the Siamese, Sophie the Pampered Princess, Montgomery the Old Gentleman, Bailey the Fat Calico, Jynx the Black, Oscar the Orange Kitten in Training, and Marlowe the Devoted Abyssinian whose place is always at Mrs. Perivale's side. Her delicate butler, Henderson, who has no desire whatsoever for adventure, swallows his fears and chases along after her, obliged to his duty to watch over her, making sure that her pills are taken on time, and tea is served as and when it should be. It is because no one believes she can, that she takes on the challenge, and she must find out for herself whether her life is really over, or if the best of it may be yet to come.

Found with a search for `fantasy novel woman magic cats orderly pills` from details I remembered from that Facebook post.

Answer (score 5):

***[Magical Midlife Madness](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/51385818-magical-midlife-madness)*** (2020) by K.F. Breene perhaps?

From Goodreads:

> "Happily Ever After" wasn't supposed to come with a do-over option. But when my husband of twenty years packs up and heads for greener pastures and my son leaves for college, that's exactly what my life becomes.
>
> Do-over.
>
> This time, though, I plan to do things differently. Age is just a number, after all, and at forty I'm ready to carve my own path.
>
> Eager for a fresh start, I make a somewhat unorthodox decision and move to a tiny town in the Sierra foothills. I'll be taking care of a centuries old house that called to me when I was a kid. It's just temporary, I tell myself. It'll just be for a while.
>
> That is, until I learn what the house really is, something I never could've imagined.
>
> Thankfully forty isn't too old to start an adventure, because that's exactly what I do. A very dangerous adventure that will change my life forever. I have a chance to start again, and this time, I make the rules.

Comment: Yes! This doesn't quite match FuzzyBoots' added details in the comments, but it is what I thought of when I read the question title. (And 40 is closer to what I'd call middle-aged than 73.)

Answer (score 0):

Karri Nichols Anderson posted a now-deleted answer with a URL, but not much more information, but pointed out that *[Aunt Jenny and the Delayed Quest](https://halflands.com/AuntJenny/)* is another work based off of that Facebook post, although it does not look like it was ever completely released.

> Aunt Jenny and the Delayed Quest is my first novel set in the Halflands. It tells the story of Jennifer Winston, retired nurse, librarian and athletics coach at the prestigious Winston Academy for Girls, who finds herself on an epic journey into the Halflands.
>
> Known to one and all as “Aunt Jenny”, Jennifer is not the sort of person who usually gets caught up in adventures, let alone heroic quests straight out of high fantasy. No, she’s got lots to keep her busy these days: gardening, long walks on the family estate, conquering her prodigious ‘to be read’ pile, tutoring and socializing with ‘her girls’—the students and faculty at the school. At least that's how it was until May Day, when the package arrived.

The most recent update as of April 2020:

> At least until I have a better idea as to how Aunt Jenny is going to be published, I'm not ready to publish excerpts or snippets, but I would like to give potential readers at least a bit of an introduction to the story, the world and the characters. My solution for this is to create a serious of short standalone pieces under the rubric “Meanwhile…”. The first of these, which takes place shortly after the opening of the book is: “[Meanwhile… Missing Persons](https://halflands.com/AuntJenny/MissingPersons.html)”. I hope you enjoy it.

....

> As it stands at the moment I’ve completed chapter sixteen, more than 80% of the novel, according to my outline, and—with the aid of stalwart friends and beta readers—gotten both feedback and some first pass copy editing. It’s well enough along, and the outline is solid enough, that I know I can finish it. That means that I need to start looking for an agent, editor or publisher who’ll show some interest in it, or failing that, I need to figure out how to go about self-publishing it.